# Can't Parse VueJS 2 hash as an empty string

Tags: javascript, hash, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm currently working on trying to determine if a hash is present in the url and I'm getting some odd results. The below code when run with a url such as `http://localhost:8080/subscribers#test` runs correctly and outputs as `#test` which is perfect, but when I simply request `http://localhost:8080/subscribers` it appears as `hash: ""`. My initial thoughts were simple `this.$route.query.hash === ''` which according to the chrome dev tools is correct. But here's where it gets odd as that alongside a `null` and `undefined` or `'undefined'` check both don't match my if statement.

```
 mounted: function () {
  if (this.$route.query.hash === '' || this.$route.query.hash === 'undefined' || this.$route.query.hash === null) {
    console.log(this.$route.hash)
    console.log(this.$route)
    console.log('grabbing auth')
  } else {
    console.log(this.$route.hash)
    console.log(this.$route)
    console.log('attempting redirect')
  }
}
```

Console out put, shows as attempting redirect:

[image]

Can someone figure out why this is or am I doing something wrong?

edit:

using `if (this.$route.query.hash) {` also provides the same odd results where the if statement is never validated as true.

Comment: `"" === null` is `false`. Is that your question? Or can you clarify?

Comment: Where's your null/undefined check? You question is not clear. `Boolean('') === false`

Comment: Let me update it with more information.

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: @thanksd no my question is why an empty value can not be asserted as an empty string or anything else despite showing it as an empty string in dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing `.query` from the statement?

Also note that if you don't fully force a refresh rather than just adding a #test and then accepting the url you will cause a dom refresh but you won't cause the router to update which is why your getting odd results from the console. If you performed a full refresh such as returning from or coming from a different website then it will parse the # correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your if statement, make your if like this :

```
if (this.$route.hash) {
        console.log('grabbing auth')
      } else {
        console.log('attempting redirect')
        }
```

Comment: This statement is always validating as false, which is why I posted on SO.

Comment: Just validated this by sending an empty string which returned as attempting redirect, Then tried sending it a hash which returned as attempting redirect.